# Managed method for SetParent() on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, window-handles, setparent

How can I show a form as a child of a window that isn't in my program?

I have a window handle to what should be the parent, but I don't see any managed method for SetParent() on a form.  Is there one?  It also seems that the `form.Show()` method only accepts managed objects implementing IWin32Window.

If there isn't a managed method, what is the preferred method for declaring the API for maximum compatibility with future systems?  Like this?:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetParent(hWndChild As IntPtr, hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Is it possible to build a class that implements IWin32Window and somehow wraps up a window?  It would be handy do something like this, but I am not familiar with IWin32Window:

```
frmMyForm.Show(New NativeWindowWrapper(12345)) 'Where 12345 is the hWnd of the window I want to wrap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, I just found the documentation on IWin32Window, and see that it is only one property... `Handle`.  Yes, then of course I can easily make this NativeWindowWrapper class...

I haven't tested it yet, but I am sure it will work just fine...

```
Public Class NativeWindowWrapper
    Implements IWin32Window

    Private _Handle As IntPtr

    Public ReadOnly Property Handle As System.IntPtr Implements System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window.Handle
        Get
            Return _Handle
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Handle As IntPtr)
        Me._Handle = Handle
    End Sub
End Class
```